# How to compare the two array and add new property and value

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
    data = [
    {
      'server': 'Network 1',
      'data': [
        {
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 05:40:01"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'server': 'Network 2',
      'data': [
      {
       download: 12,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 05:40:01"
      },
      {
       download: 12,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 05:50:01"
      },
      {
       download: 12,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 06:00:01"
      },
      {
       download: 12,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 06:10:01"
      }
    ]}
  ]
```

What I'm trying to do is to compare the two array based on the dateStart for example 2020-10-09 04:40:01 then in other array there's no 2020-10-09 04:40:01.
it will add object like this.

```
  data = [
    {
      'server': 'Network 1',
      'data': [
      {
       download: 12,
       dateStart: "2020-09-20 05:40:01"
      },
      {
        download: 0,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 05:50:01"
      },
      {
        download: 0,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 06:00:01"
      },
      {
        download: 0,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 06:10:01"
      }
    ]
}, 
{
      'server': 'Network 1',
      'data': [
      {
       download: 12,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 05:40:01"
      },
      {
       download: 12,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 05:50:01"
      },
      {
       download: 12,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 06:00:01"
      },
      {
       download: 12,
        dateStart: "2020-09-20 06:10:01"
      }
    ]
}
  ]
```

if array doesn't equal to the dateStart it should add an object like the first array has an "dateStart": "2020-10-09 04:40:01" then in second array doesn't have then it should add the new object. if the first doesn't have the "dateStart": "2020-10-09 04:40:01" then second has "dateStart": "2020-10-09 04:40:01" then on first array it will add the new object.

here's the sample:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqgn2w?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest straight forward method is to use a for each loop

```
// for each element in data[0], search a match in data[1]
// if there is no matching data in data[1], push the corresponding element to data[1]
data[0].forEach(d => {
  // search for a match in data[1]
  match = data[1].find(element => element.dateStart === d.dateStart)
  if (match.length === 0) { // if there is not a match
    data[1].push({
      "server": "Network 2",
      "ping": "0 ms",
      "dl": "0 Mbit/s",
      "ul": "0 Mbit/s",
      "ispcon": false,
      "dateStart": d.dateStart,
      "dateEnd": d.dateEnd
    }
  }
})
```

Same goes for other elements in the data array, but I'll leave that loop for you to write.

Edit: dynamic version to support more than 2 items in data array

```
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.data.forEach(record => {
        // search for a match in each of the other item
        data.forEach(d2 => {
            sameExist = d2.data.find(element => element.dateStart == record.dateStart)
            if (!sameExist) {
                d2.data.push({
                    "server": d2.server,
                    "dateStart": record.dateStart
                })
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqgn2w?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: How to make dynamic

Comment: Like for example there's a new server which is the server 3 and it has a data also

Comment: You can just add a nested loop to loop through all the elements in the data array

Comment: If you don't know how, I suggest you to read some more tutorials on array and their operations in Javascript first.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: How? is it ok to provide a sample.

Comment: I've added the example code, you can take a look at it. But I advise you to revisit the basics of array operations or you will get stuck at these fundamental questions quite a lot.

Comment: This is also not the optimal method in terms of complexity, because the complexity grows with the number of items it inserted. A better method would be to separate the modified array and the new array, but I'll also leave that part to you. Please mark my answer as accepted if that helped.

Comment: it didn't meet the expected output. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqgn2w?file=src/app/app.component.ts here's the code and below expected output

Comment: I edited a bit of the code and ran it once myself, should work now.

Comment: I tried it, thanks. is it ok to use the orderBy inside the forEach? cause I will arrange the date to descending.